# How to make comparison between two dates in angular5?

Tags: angular, angular5, custom-validators

I'm trying in angular5 to not validate a form if the second date input is greater than the first date input and then show an error message ,so the user can change the date .

This is .html file :

```
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addProjecToClients()">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Choisir un client : </label>


          <div class="col-sm-6">

            <ng-select  *ngIf="_listClients"
                         [items]="_listClients"
                          bindLabel ="nom"
                          bindValue ="id"
                        [(ngModel)]="selectedPersonId"
                        formControlName="selectedPersonId"
                         >
            </ng-select>

          </div>
        </div>

        <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Information liées au contrat : </label>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" >Date one :  </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                   placeholder=".form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="dateOne"
formControlName="dateOne">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" for="input-small">Date two : </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="date" id="input-small" name="input-small" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                   placeholder=".form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="dateTwo" 
    formControlName="dateTwo">

 <span style="color:red" *ngIf="validation()">DateTwo must be gt than dateone</span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  [disabled]="!form.valid" >Save changes</button>

</form>
```

This is .ts File :

```
 export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

    dateOne:new Date() ;
    dateTwo:new Date(); 

     ngOnInit() {

    this.doSearch();
    this.dateOne= null;
    this.dateTwo= null;

 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      dateOne: ['', Validators.required],
      dateTwo: ['', Validators.required],
       selectedPersonId: ['', Validators.required]
    });

}

validation(){
    if(this.dateOne && this.dateTwo){
      if(this.dateOne.getTime() < this.dateTwo.getTime()){
        return false;
      }
      else
        return true;
    }

      }

    }
```

I was advised to use custom validators, but I couldn't find a complete simple example.

Any help :) ?

Comment: If you are looking for information on custom validators, this could help https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2

Comment: Thank you for this link  , i'll absolutely read it :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by using this code `getTime()` to compare in milliseconds.

```
if(dateOne.getTime() > dateTwo.getTime())
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for ansewring , How can i show the error message  ? do i need custom validator ?

Comment: Where is the error message? and where do you want to show?

Comment: Let me please explain to you : i want two cases , 1)-when dateOne>dateTwo , the user can submit ,2)-when dateOne<dateTwo an error message appears behind the input saying for exemple ' Error  :The input dateOne should be greater than input dateTwo  , please modify the date .. ' like this . in project.component.html behind the input or above .

Comment: Ok, actually angular has  `FormBuilder` from Angular/forms take a look because it is easier to use, but if you no want used you must add a simple <form> with a submit action. 
However to display an error  you must do the validation in this function `addProjecToClients()` and just show an error in html document

Comment: yes let me build it  in the mean time modify your post por add this feature to your post

Comment: What feature should i add to the post ?

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-abel-wrpmll) Example with a simple validation error, obviously you must edited to adapt to your code it is just to show that is easier by using reactive forms (put numbers in the inputs haven't validate with dates)

Comment: thank you for your help , i appreciate it , but how can i avoid the error message before entering the second number ? i want it to appear only when the condition is not achieved .